How to create HH:MM optimized regex?
Given two times in the form HH:MM, I want to filter logs containing all hours between the given hours.
So for example, given 09:30 and 15:30, a simple regex T(09:[345]|1[01234]|15:[123]) would suffice. There is the assumption that input is in correct format.
Creating a regex like, T(09:30|09:31|09:32|.....|15:30) is a trivial simple loop, but I wonder what transformations could I do to optimize such a regex and if such transformations are worth it.
I am writing in python and this is my current code. If it simplifies, I am open to any Unix tools.
from dataclasses import dataclass
import datetime
import re

@dataclass
class TimeFilter:
   start: datetime.time
   stop: datetime.time

   def timergx(self):
     i = self.start.hour * 60 + self.start.minute
     stop = self.stop.hour * 60 + self.stop.minute
     return "T(" + "|".join(f"{x // 60:02d}:{x % 60:02d}" for x in range(i, stop)) + ")"

def HHMM2time(txt: str):
    return datetime.time(*[int(x) for x in txt.split(":")])

tf = TimeFilter(HHMM2time("9:30"), HHMM2time("15:30"))
assert re.match(rf.timergx(), "T10:30")

How to "generate" the regex so it is "faster"? Or, is the regex in the form T(09:30|09:31|09:32|.....|15:30) actually "faster" to process than any optimized form? If relevant, GO regex engine will be using the regex.

Your original regex T(09:[345]|1[01234]|15:[123]) is vastly superior. To match anything other than T09:30 takes more - up to 70 times more - steps with the generated regex. See https://regex101.com/r/MiwuWI/1 and https://regex101.com/r/p9cQpD/1

Yes, I suspected that, because after every wrong match, regex engine has to "roll back" 5 characters and start the match with the next group again. So I believe the rolling back is costly, which is why there is room for optimization.

@Nick: "vastly superior" but wrong since it allows T15:35 and forbids T15:01. Also if the final goal is to use it with Go's re2 engine, I doubt that counting the steps of a backtracking engine like PCRE gives a good overview. Whatever I think too that the way to go is a short and factorized pattern because in fine only the (ridiculous) time taken to parse and compile the pattern changes. I would not let capturing groups in the pattern, only non-capturing groups. To finish, I will not use a regex to compare hours or dates.

About the giant alternation: some regex engines like PCRE are able to optimize an alternation when this one is at the ground level (not in a group) and when each branch start with literal characters (indexes of these literal parts are searched in the string with a fast algorithm before the normal walk of the engine and then the pattern is only tested at the found indexes). But this optimization has probably a limit or becomes uninteresting with too many branches. Note that regex101 doesn't take this optimization in account and returns a number of steps like this one doesn't exist.

but wrong since it allows T15:35 and forbids T15:01 Right, I mixed 0 with 3. So I think it should rather be T(09:[345]|1[01234]|15:[012]). It "feels" to me like generating such a regex or optimizing it should be simple, however I don't seem to find an algorithm for doing it.

Here is a function to build a similar regex dynamically:
import re

def single_digit(start, end):
    if start == end:
        return str(start)
    if int(start) == int(end) - 1:
        return f"[{start}{end}]"
    return f"[{start}-{end}]"


def make_regex_rec(start, end, high="23:59", need_brackets=False):
    if "00:00".endswith(start) and high.endswith(end):
        return ""
    left = start[0]
    start = start[1:]
    right = end[0]
    end = end[1:]
    n = len(start)
    if not n:
        return single_digit(left, right)
    high = ("3:59" if left == "2" and n == 4 else "9:59")[-n:]
    if left == right:
        return left + make_regex_rec(start, end, high, True)
    rest_left = make_regex_rec(start, high, high, True)
    high = ("3:59" if right == "2" and n == 4 else "9:59")[-n:]
    rest_right = make_regex_rec("00:00"[-n:], end, high, True)
    left = int(left)
    right = int(right)
    if rest_left:
        rest_left = f"{left}{rest_left}"
        left += 1
    if rest_right:
        rest_right = f"{right}{rest_right}"
        right -= 1
    rest_mid = single_digit(left, right) if right - left >= 0 else ""
    res = "|".join(filter(None, [rest_left, rest_mid, rest_right]))
    return f"(?:{res})" if need_brackets else res

def make_regex(start, end):
    if not re.match(r"\d\d:[0-5]\d", start):
        raise ValueError("start time has wrong format") 
    if not re.match(r"\d\d:[0-5]\d", end) or end > "23:59":
        raise ValueError("end time has wrong format or is out of range") 
    if start > end:
        raise ValueError("start time must not be greater then end time")
    return "^" + make_regex_rec(start, end, "23:59", True)

Demo run:
regex = make_regex("19:00", "23:59")
print(regex)
regex = make_regex("09:30", "15:30")
print(regex)

The output is:
^(?:19|2)
^(?:09:(?:[3-5])|1(?:[0-4]|5:(?:[0-3])))

If you plan to use the regex with re.match, then you don't really need the ^ anchor, as re.match requires a match to be a prefix of the input string. In that case you can have this line as last statement in make_regex:
return make_regex_rec(start, end, "23:59", False)

Then the output will be:
19|2
09:(?:[3-5])|1(?:[0-4]|5:(?:[0-3]))

